# Unity Service Locator: Is there a supplied way to test configuration is valid?

Tags: unit-testing, unity-container, service-locator

In StructureMap there is a way to test your configuration is valid calling StructureMap.ObjectFactory:

**Is there an equivalent for this in Unity?**

```
[Test]
public void Test_StructureMap_Configuration_IsValid()
{
    LocalConfiguration.ConfigureStructureMap();
    ObjectFactory.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that feature is unique to StructureMap as far as I know.